# postgres select top 10 records per user

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose i have a **user_data** table which contains multiple records of users.

```
id       user_id  col1    col2  created_at
1        1        abc     x     2019-01-04
2        2        def     x     2019-02-01
3        3        ghi     x     2019-03-05
4        2        jkl     x     2019-07-07
5        2        mno     x     2019-06-01
6        3        pqr     x     2019-07-11
```

Now i want to select top 10 latest records per user in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select ud.*
from (select ud.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by created_at desc) as seqnum
      from user_data ud
     ) ud
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Comment: ok. As inner query is fetching all the records first, will it affect the performance if **user_data**  table is large. If yes then should i fetch top 10 records for each user separately by using **limit**  clause inside a loop.

Comment: @JohnWick . . . This should be faster than a look that executes separate queries.